# How to translate a italian text string to english text string using google translate API service?

Tags: php, ajax

Here is my code and I am trying to translate a Italian string to English, for this I am using google API service.

My Aim is to translate a Ajax response text which is in Italian to English.

code:

```
$str = "L'illuminazione è il loro mestiere";
$to_lan = "en";
$from_lan = "it";
GoogleTranslate ($str, $to_lan, $from_lan);
function GoogleTranslate ( $str, $to_lan, $from_lan )
{
    $data = file_get_contents ( "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/translate?v=1.0&q=" . urlencode($str) . "&langpair=" . $from_lan . "%7C" . $to_lan );
    $data = json_decode ( $data );
if ( $data->responseStatus == 200 )
{
    echo $data->responseData->translatedText;
    //return $data->responseData->translatedText;
}
else
{
    echo "Server down.";
}
}
```

Comment: There is no question in here.

Comment: ohh, so sorry. I am editing the question.

Comment: Still not very clear what the problem is your are having.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you forgot to add languages:

```
$to_lan = "en";
$from_lan = "it";
GoogleTranslate ($str, $to_lan, $from_lan);
```

or

```
GoogleTranslate ($str, "it", "en");
```

Comment: I printed the $data variable and got this message:

Comment: stdClass Object ( [responseData] => [responseDetails] => Suspected Terms of Service Abuse. Please see http://code.google.com/apis/errors [responseStatus] => 403 ) Server down.

Comment: They think you broke Terms of Service, you have to contact them in the link you posted if you don't.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at **Google Translate API > Libraries and Samples**  **[here](https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/libraries)**

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&q=select%20%2a%20from%20google.translate%20where%20q=%22this%20is%20a%20test%22%20and%20target=%22de%22;) and parse the XML/JSON response.